# How to re-initialize the bootstrap datetimepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, datetimepicker

I have a Two datetimepicker on my page. Name as 'SartDate' and 'EndDate'.Select the date on StartDate, this date set as a minDate of 'EndDate'.First time is work Correctly.But the date of 'StartDate' reset, the minDate of 'EndDate' Not 
re-initiliaz

```
var date = null;
    $("#jobPublishDate").bind("keyup blur change mouseup", function () {
    $('#jobPublishDate').datetimepicker({ format: 'DD/MM/YYYY H:mm', showTodayButton: true, showClear: true, showClose: true });
        var from = $("#jobPublishDate").val().split("/");
        var newdate = from[1] + "/" + (from[0]) + "/" +from[2];
        var f = new Date(newdate);
        date = f;
    });

    $("#jobCloseDate").focusin(function () {
    $('#jobCloseDate').datetimepicker({ format: 'DD/MM/YYYY H:mm', showTodayButton: true, showClear: true, showClose: true, minDate: date });
           });
       });
```

```html
<label>StartDate></label>
<input ng-model="job.StrPublishDate" id="jobPublishDate">
<br/>
<label>EndDate></label>
<input ng-model="job.StrCloseDate" id="jobCloseDate">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var date = null;
$("#jobPublishDate").bind("keyup blur change mouseup", function () {
var from = $("#jobPublishDate").val().split("/");
var newdate = from[1] + "/" + (from[0]) + "/" + from[2];
var f = new Date(newdate);
date = f;
$("#jobPublishDate").on('dp.change', function (e) {
var dp = $('#jobCloseDate').data('DateTimePicker');
if (typeof dp !== 'undefined') {
dp.minDate(e.date);
} 
else {
date = e.date;
}
});

$("#jobCloseDate").focusin(function () {
$('#jobCloseDate').datetimepicker({ format: 'DD/MM/YYYY H:mm', showTodayButton: true, showClear: true, showClose: true, minDate: date });
});
```

Fellow this Code and Solve the Problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hook to the `dp.change` event (fired when the date has been selected) an use `minDate` method to set the minimum date on the second picker.

```
var date = null;

$("#jobPublishDate").bind("keyup blur change mouseup", function () {
    $('#jobPublishDate').datetimepicker({ format: 'DD/MM/YYYY H:mm', showTodayButton: true, showClear: true, showClose: true })
    var from = $("#jobPublishDate").val().split("/");
    var newdate = from[1] + "/" + (from[0]) + "/" +from[2];
    var f = new Date(newdate);
    date = f;
});

// Adds the date change event to the first picker
$("#jobPublishDate").on('db.change', function (e) {
    // Get the DateTimePicker instance
    var dp = $('#jobCloseDate').data('DateTimePicker');
    // If the second picker has been initialized
    if(typeof dp !== 'undefined') {
        // Set the minimum date on the second picker
        dp.minDate(e.date);
    } else {
        // If the close date picker is not initialized, stores the date for later use
        date = e.date;
    }
});

$("#jobCloseDate").focusin(function () {
    $('#jobCloseDate').datetimepicker({ format: 'DD/MM/YYYY H:mm', showTodayButton: true, showClear: true, showClose: true, minDate: date });
});
```

You can find out more about DateTimePicker methods [here](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/).

Comment: Use this Code not work properly the keyup blur function call only

Comment: @RehmatAli i don’t understand what you are saying.

Comment: I Set the min Date in EndDate Picker according to the selected date of  StartDate Picker,  first time min Date Set accurately but the StartDate Change in Edit Case Change the StartDate picker value this value not set in min Date of EndDate Picker  the min Date not re-initialize in Edit Case only Set the firstly time  Selected SatartDate picker value not Change in min Date

Comment: @RehmatAli i really struggle trying to understand what you are trying to explain. :S Can you test it now? I've updated my code. Please create a fiddle so we can test it.